# Minecraft windows 10 edition redeem code error

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I clicked to redeem the Minecraft Windows 10 edition in my Mojang account I was redirected to the login page of the Microsoft account, then I accidentally close the browser. I re-opened it, and enter my Mojang account, clicked in redeem again and then i got this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /webblend

Comment: How do i do that? I couldnt find any redeem buttons in the Store.

Comment: I decided to create [tag:minecraft-windows-10] for now. Once this version is functionally identical to PE, we can synomymize the two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to https://account.mojang.com and look for ***Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition Beta***.
   There is a table with a **Gift card** column: Copy the given key to your clipboard (<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>).
2. Open the Windows 10 *Store* app, click onto your profile picture and select *redeem code* (or similar, my store is not english).
3. Now log in to your Microsoft account and paste the copied gift code into the only input box and hit *Redeem*.

Answer (score 0):

The URL is actually broken. When being redirected to the Microsoft page, you have to remove the #/ at the end of the URL and hit enter again. Then you can redeem your code on the Microsoft page.